# Constant function on a convex set

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

If $f'(x;y)=0$ for every $x$ in an open convex set $S$ and every $y$ in $R^n$, prove that $f$ is constant on $S$.

A set $S$ is called convex if for every $a$ and $b$ in $S$, ${ta+(1-t)b \epsilon S}.$

$f'(x;y)$ is the directional derivative at $x$ in the direction $y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea here is to use the mean value theorem.Pick a point $a \in S$, and any point point $x \in S$ then the segment $[a,x]$ lies in  $S$ by convexity. Then by the mean value theorem there is a point c such that $f(x)-f(a)=\sum_{i=1}^n D_if(c)(x_i-a_i)$ but $D_if=0$ for all $i$, thus $f(x)=f(a)$. Since $x$ was arbitrary $f$ is constant on $S$.

Comment: can you explain why is $D_if=0$ for all $i$.

Comment: @ajinkya this is you assumption. By $D_i f$ I mean the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to the $i$th variable. ($\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}$)